# Segmentation fault when using erlang:trace/3 in OTP 19 erts-8.0

Tags: segmentation-fault, erlang, trace

I'm new to Erlang, but seem to have ran into a brick wall quite quickly. 
I'm trying to learn proper usage of erlang:trace/3 and its cohorts. Here 
is my example program:

```
-module(seg_fault).
-export([start/0]).

simple_tracer() ->
  io:format("enter"),
  receive
    _ -> io:format("msg"), simple_tracer
  end.

start() ->
  Simple = spawn(fun simple_tracer/0),
  erlang:trace_pattern({'_','_','_'}, true, [local]),
  erlang:trace(self(),
    true,
    [send,
    'receive',
    procs,
    ports,
    garbage_collection,
    monotonic_timestamp,
    set_on_first_spawn,
    set_on_first_link,
    call,
    return_to,
    {tracer, Simple},
    arity]),
  math:sqrt(2),
  math:sqrt(3),
  erlang:trace_delivered(self()),
  receive
    {trace_delivered, _, _} -> undefined
  end,
  erlang:trace(self(),false,[all]),
  io:format("complete!").
```

I am on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine that is my workstation. Here is what 
happens when I run it using 'erlc' and 'erl'

```
[ericu-destroyer-of-worlds] ~$ erlc ./seg_fault.erl
seg_fault.erl:27: Warning: the result of the expression is ignored 
(suppress the warning by assigning the expression to the _ variable)
seg_fault.erl:28: Warning: the result of the expression is ignored 
(suppress the warning by assigning the expression to the _ variable)
[ericu-destroyer-of-worlds] ~$ erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0] [source-6dc93c1] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] 
[async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.0  (abort with ^G)
1> seg_fault:start().
entermsgSegmentation fault
```

It looks like my process that should receive the trace messages starts 
and gets a message without issue. However, the process crashes on my 
second call of erlang:trace/3 with How set to false. My understanding is 
this should just turn off tracing for the current process, identified by 
self().

I ran the same code using a slightly older version of Erlang

```
root@ba8246924352:/# erlc ./seg_fault.erl
seg_fault.erl:27: Warning: the result of the expression is ignored 
(suppress the warning by assigning the expression to the _ variable)
seg_fault.erl:28: Warning: the result of the expression is ignored 
(suppress the warning by assigning the expression to the _ variable)
root@ba8246924352:/# erl
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] 
[async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.3.1  (abort with ^G)
1> seg_fault:start().
entermsgcomplete!ok
```

It seems to work just fine on this older version. Is this a problem with 
Erlang or is it an error in my usage of erlang:trace/3? If there is any 
other data I could provide that could help in troubleshooting this 
problem, please let me know.

**Update**

I still have no idea what is going on, but I did notice that if I use input from a file rather than a terminal, erlang does not crash

```
[ericu-destroyer-of-worlds] ~$ cat erl.in
seg_fault:start().
[ericu-destroyer-of-worlds] ~$ erl < ~/erl.in
Eshell V8.0  (abort with ^G)
1> entermsgcomplete!ok
2> *** Terminating erlang (nonode@nohost)
[ericu-destroyer-of-worlds] ~$ erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0] [source-6dc93c1] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.0  (abort with ^G)
1> seg_fault:start().
entermsgSegmentation fault
```

I am able to reproduce the seg fault when running using GDB. I built Erlang OTP 19 without optimizations and with debugging symbols.

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb) file ./bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/erlexec
Reading symbols from ./bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/erlexec...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/ericu/builds/otp_src_19.0/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/erlexec 
process 3251 is executing new program: /home/ericu/builds/otp_src_19.0/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/beam.smp
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffb50ff700 (LWP 3255)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb3abf700 (LWP 3256)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff7ff7700 (LWP 3257)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb516e700 (LWP 3258)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb3f30700 (LWP 3259)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb32be700 (LWP 3260)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb317f700 (LWP 3261)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb315d700 (LWP 3262)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb313b700 (LWP 3263)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb3119700 (LWP 3264)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb30f7700 (LWP 3265)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb30d5700 (LWP 3266)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb2e3f700 (LWP 3268)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb263e700 (LWP 3269)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb1e3d700 (LWP 3270)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb163c700 (LWP 3271)]
[New Thread 0x7fffb0c3b700 (LWP 3272)]
[New Thread 0x7fff7bfff700 (LWP 3273)]
[New Thread 0x7fff7b7fe700 (LWP 3274)]
[New Thread 0x7fff7abbf700 (LWP 3275)]
[New Thread 0x7fff7a3be700 (LWP 3276)]
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.0  (abort with ^G)
1> seg_fault:start().
entermsg
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffb2e3f700 (LWP 3268)]
0x00000000004c4a85 in lookup_tracer_nif (tracer=18446744073709551611) at beam/erl_trace.c:2763
2763        tnif_tmpl.module = ERTS_TRACER_MODULE(tracer);
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004c4a85 in lookup_tracer_nif (tracer=18446744073709551611) at beam/erl_trace.c:2763
#1  0x00000000004c4f00 in send_to_tracer_nif_raw (c_p=0x7fffb5380400, tracee=0x7fffb5380400, tracer=18446744073709551611, tracee_flags=0, t_p_id=1992864826275, tnif=0x0, 
    topt=TRACE_FUN_T_CALL, tag=32331, msg=140735234699146, extra=0, pam_result=75) at beam/erl_trace.c:2844
#2  0x00000000004c5340 in send_to_tracer_nif (c_p=0x7fffb5380400, t_p=0x7fffb5380400, t_p_id=1992864826275, tnif=0x0, topt=TRACE_FUN_T_CALL, tag=32331, msg=140735234699146, extra=0, 
    pam_result=75) at beam/erl_trace.c:2923
#3  0x00000000004c073c in erts_trace_return_to (p=0x7fffb5380400, pc=0x7fffb2ea3758) at beam/erl_trace.c:1028
#4  0x000000000046ad27 in erts_bif_trace (bif_index=129, p=0x7fffb5380400, args=0x7fffb5ec00c0, I=0x7fffb2ea3758) at beam/beam_bp.c:868
#5  0x00000000004ba0cd in wrap_erts_internal_trace_3 (p=0x7fffb5380400, args=0x7fffb5ec00c0, I=0x7fffb2ea3758) at x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/erl_bif_wrap.c:723
#6  0x0000000000440057 in process_main () at beam/beam_emu.c:2849
#7  0x000000000051e63d in sched_thread_func (vesdp=0x7fffb3e04240) at beam/erl_process.c:8153
#8  0x00000000006b8787 in thr_wrapper (vtwd=0x7fffffffd060) at pthread/ethread.c:114
#9  0x00007ffff7278184 in start_thread (arg=0x7fffb2e3f700) at pthread_create.c:312
#10 0x00007ffff6d9d37d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111
(gdb)
```

Based on the presence of `erts_trace_return_to` it is in the process of trying to deliver a trace tuple when it crashes.

Comment: There is mail conference http://erlang.org/mailman/listinfo/erlang-bugs where this issue will meet a much more appropriate audience. You should not be able to crash BEAM VM in this way.

Comment: Including the `return_to` trace flag causes an error where the internal function `lookup_tracer_nif` essentially tries to take the head of an empty list. The argument it receives, `tracer=18446744073709551611`, is the nil tracer.

Comment: The OTP folks are aware of this problem and will be posting a fix to [the Erlang repository](https://github.com/erlang/otp) soon.

Comment: Thank you @SteveVinoski ! I was getting worried about this for a while. Can you post a link somewhere to the bug in an issue tracker?

Comment: @EricUrban: I don't know that this issue is in a bug tracker, but you can find the commit for the fix [here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/53bf2a9593a2f34151016f7d84fad6d213d76ee9), and it was merged to the [OTP master](https://github.com/erlang/otp/tree/master) branch [in this commit](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/8ae4ab7c4839a19b1b2e8fc28087c0471d8dbd87).